# how to find and stop/kill processes started from shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, master-slave, kill-process

I plan to start a bunch of processes and background them from within a shell script and I am looking for good ways to later identify those processes in my cleanup function or script. Assuming my start function looks like this:

```bash
function start_slaves() {
  for i in $(find $HOME -type d -name "slv-*")
  do
    BN=$(basename "$i")
    cd "$i" && pestpp tussock_full.pst /H localhost:5050 > "$HOME/$BN.log" 2>&1 &
    echo "Started slave in: '$i'"
  done
}
```

### Additional Info

Each process communicates with a master process started independently (`localhost:5050` in this case). If I start each slave process manually (from my shell, not from a script), and I don't send the process to the background with a trailing `&`, I can easily kill it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. I need a scriptable solution because it quickly becomes impractical to have `N` separate shells/terminal windows open to manage `N` slave process. So I want a way to start and kill the processes in bulk. FWIW, I am developing this using bash on Fedora, but it would be awfully nice if I could find a solution that is not too platform specific as I will eventually need to be able to run on Ubuntu, OSX, and CentOS.

Comment: `killall pestpp`. That's one way. Difficult to know if that is what you need without knowing your exact requirements and constraints beyond "how to kill processes in bulk".

Comment: I think my master process name will also be `pestpp` and I don't want to kill that one.

Comment: Include all relevant constraints/requirements in your question (not just in the comments). Could write each pid to a variable or file and then iterate over the pids (`$!` gives the process id of the last command). There are tons of different ways to do what you want so it's not clear what specifically you need help on that isn't just the full solution.

Comment: As @kaylum says, if you're shutting it down from the same process, the conventional thing to do is to store the PIDs on startup (`foo & foo_pids+=( $! )`).

Comment: btw, `for i in $(find ...)` is very bad form -- you'll have unpleasant things happen if any filenames contain whitespace (even worse is if they contain newlines). http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Complex_actions has a full discussion; a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) loop over the output of `find -print0` is another best-practices approach.

Comment: BTW, if you care about portability, consider ditching the `function` keyword; the POSIX-compliant way to declare a function is just `start_slaves() {`, with no `function` preceding it.

Comment: ...insofar as Linux is concerned, by the way, `fuser` is your friend. Easy to ask it to kill -- for instance -- all processes *connected to* `localhost:5050` (but not, say, the actual process running that service).

Answer (score 0):

List all **connections to** `localhost:5050`:

```
lsof -Pi | grep '>localhost:5050'
```

Kill all processes **connected to** `localhost:5050`:

```
kill `lsof -Pi | grep '>localhost:5050' | awk '{print$2}'`
```